# Error al reestructurar un dataframe

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe (all_blast_df2_Oakwood) como este:

```
     lib           virus_names
     PV005       Watermelon mosaic virus
     PV005       Watermelon mosaic virus
     PV005       Cowpea aphid-borne mosaic virus
     PV005       Yam bean mosaic virus
     PV005       Watermelon mosaic virus
     PV006       Watermelon mosaic virus
     PV006       Cowpea aphid-borne mosaic virus
     PV008       Cucumis mosaic virus
     PV008       Watermelon mosaic virus
     PV010       Watermelon mosaic virus
```

A partir del anterior dataframe me gustaría obtener una tabla como esta:

```
     lib      virus_names
     PV005    Watermelon mosaic virus/Cowpea aphid-borne mosaic virus/Yam bean mosaic virus
     PV006    Watermelon mosaic virus/Cowpea aphid-borne mosaic virus
     PV008    Cucumis mosaic virus/Watermelon mosaic virus
     PV010    Watermelon mosaic virus
```

Para ello aplico el siguiente comando:

```
c<-all_blast_df2_Oakwood %>%
 group_by(lib) %>%
 summarise(virus_names=paste(virus_names,collapse='/'))
```

Pero obtengo lo siguiente:

```
     lib      virus_names
     PV005    Watermelon mosaic virus/Watermelon mosaic virus/Cowpea aphid-borne mosaic virus/Yam bean mosaic virus/Watermelon mosaic virus
     PV006    Watermelon mosaic virus/Cowpea aphid-borne mosaic virus
     PV008    Cucumis mosaic virus/Watermelon mosaic virus
     PV010    Watermelon mosaic virus
```

No logro eliminar los nombres de los virus que aparecen por duplicado en cada librería (lib). 
Me gustaría saber como eliminar los duplicados y a raiz de este último dataframe obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
  Watermelon mosaic virus 100% #(aparece en 4 lib de 4)
  Cowpea aphid-borne mosaic virus 50% #(aparece en 2 lib de 4)
  Yam bean mosaic virus 25 % #(aparece en 1 lib de 4)
  Cucumis mosaic virus 25 % #(aparece en 1 lib de 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`unique()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html) para eliminar duplicados de cada grupo:

```
all_blast_df2_Oakwood %>%
    group_by(lib) %>% 
    summarize(virus=paste(unique(virus_names),collapse=' /')) -> final
```

Un comentario aparte, en tu ejemplo estás asignado esta salida a la variable `c`, no te lo recomiendo por que terminas redefiniendo la función base `c()

Comment: funciona con la correción que me has dado, muchas gracias Patricio